# ubuntu 12.04 install fontforge No package 'zlib' found

Tags: ubuntu, installation, zlib, fontforge

1,when i try  ./configure
it says:

> ```
> checking for ZLIB... configure: error: Package requirements (zlib) were not met:
>
> No package 'zlib' found
>
> Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
> installed software in a non-standard prefix.
>
> Alternatively, you may set the environment variables ZLIB_CFLAGS
> and ZLIB_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
> See the pkg-config man page for more details.
> ```

2,and i try to install zlib use aptitude it says

> ```
> packages contain "zlib" in their name:
>   libio-compress-zlib-perl libcompress-raw-zlib-perl libcompress-zlib-perl 
>   gambas2-gb-compress-zlib libghc6-zlib-dev libghc6-zlib-doc libzlib-ruby 
>   zlibc zlib-bin libghc6-zlib-prof zlib-gst gambas2-gb-compress-bzlib2 
>   haskell-zlib-doc libio-zlib-perl zlib1g-dbg zlib1g-dev 
>   libghc6-zlib-prof-0.5.2.0-b96bd zlib1g libzlib-ruby1.8 libjzlib-java 
>   libghc6-zlib-dev-0.5.2.0-b96bd 
> No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
> 0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 69 not upgraded.
> Need to get 0B of archives. After unpacking 0B will be used.
> Writing extended state information... Done
> Reading package lists... Done             
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> Reading extended state information       
> Initializing package states... Done
> ```

3,finally i installed zlib1g but the fontforge configure can't find zlib too
dpkg -l zlib1g

> ```
> Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
> | Status=Not/Inst/Cfg-files/Unpacked/Failed-cfg/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
> |/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
> ||/ Name           Version        Description
> +++-==============-==============-============================================
> ii  zlib1g         1:1.2.3.3.dfsg compression library - runtime
> ```

is it need to config  environment variables ZLIB_CFLAGS and ZLIB_LIBS
how to ?

Answer (score 8):

You are compiling something from source, so you need the headers available, and these are always in the -dev package i.e. zlib1g-dev.